# How to do a decentralized blockchain filesharing p2p program?

Tags: blockchain, distributed, p2p, file-sharing

Hello everyone thanks for reading this! I'm not fluent in this language, sorry.
I'm searching on how to make file-sharing p2p decentralized system using blockchain.
I watched that few tutorial avalaible on the internet but i don't finded nothing!
I don't really know what to do.
My project is basically pure fully p2p file-sharing with blockchains.
Help please, thanks in advance.